# Subclassing and "promote" objects

Tags: objective-c, ios, subclassing

I have a classes:

```
BasicObject : NSObject

AdvObject : BasicObject
```

in other class i make an instance by:

```
BasicObject *bObj = [[BasicObject alloc] initWithSomething:propertyOne andSomethingElse:propertyTwo];
```

BasicObject have two properties:

```
@interface BasicObject : NSObject

-(id)initWithSomething:propertyOne andSomethingElse:propertyTwo;

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString* propertyOne;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray* propertyTwo;
```

And then in initializer:

```
-(id)initWithSomething:propertyOne andSomethingElse:propertyTwo
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        _propertyOne = propertyOne;
        _propertyTwo = propertyTwo;

        if(!propertyTwo) //this is not valid condition i know, not important here
          {
             AdvObject *aObj = [[AdvObject alloc] initWithBasic:self]; //here it what i'm more concern about
             return aObj;
          }
    }

    return self;
}
```

So there in AdvObject class in initializer i have:

```
@implementation AdvObject

@synthesize basics = _basics;


-(id)initWithBasic:(BasicObject *)bObj
{
    if(self = [super init]) {
        _basics = bObj;
    }

    return self;
}
```

And after that when i return this object of course i have a object.basics filled properly, but why i can't access object.propertyOne? (this is nil). What i'm doing wrong? Is this a right design?

Comment: You should almost never, EVER return something other than `self` or `nil` in an initializer. It sends ARC into a hell hole, and referenced code into oblivion. Many, many hours have been spent debugging poorly written code like that above. If you need to return an object of a different class, do it in `+alloc`.

Comment: Thank you, I will remember that. But `+alloc` i think is not solution for me. I have a object and if that object satisfies the conditions it have to become another object. How to achieve that?

Comment: +1 for `+alloc`. This is how class clusters work.

Comment: @SimpleMan use the format `+objectWithProperty1:property2:`.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII So i should use ***only*** class method with alloc with object initialization and from there return objects to my "manager class" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or, you could avoid this entire pattern as being overly clever and create a class factory method that returns either a `BasicObject` or an `AdvObject` depending on the parameters that were passed to it.

Comment: class factory? I have many objects not just two classes (i simplify the problem for the question). Can you tell me some more about it? As far as i understand i shuld create an abstract class which should create many objects. But I really don't know how to do this in objective-c. I don't know there is a solution like that in iOS.

Comment: It's not anything specific to iOS, just a class method such as `+ (id)objectForParameter:(NSString *)selector;`.  Inside, it creates and returns whatever kind of object the selector indicates.  Of course, "selector" can be as complicated as you need...a dictionary, for example.  It would also be easier on the caller if the method's return value was a base class or an id with a protocol instead of a bare id, but that's details.

Answer (score 0):

Your `init...` method would need to do a couple of things differently, as shown below:

```
- (id)initWithSomething:propertyOne andSomethingElse:propertyTwo
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        if (!propertyTwo)
        {
             self = [[AdvObject alloc] initWithBasic:self];
        }

        _propertyOne = propertyOne;
        _propertyTwo = propertyTwo;
    }

    return self;
}
```

I haven't actually tried this with ARC, so you'd need to test this carefully.